# How to also select row count from following query? - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, rowcount

Need to also select the row/record count using the following query in Oracle SQL. How would I go about doing this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.OWNER AS TABLE_SCHEMA, t.Table_Name, c.COLUMN_NAME, c.DATA_TYPE, 
                ( 
                    SELECT CASE WHEN cons.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'P' THEN 'Primary Key' ELSE NULL END 
                    FROM SYS.all_cons_columns cols 
                        INNER JOIN SYS.all_constraints cons ON cons.constraint_name=cols.constraint_name AND cons.constraint_type = 'P' 
                    WHERE cols.Column_name=c.column_name AND cols.TABLE_NAME=c.TABLE_NAME AND cols.OWNER=c.OWNER 
                ) AS CONSTRAINT_TYPE, c.DATA_PRECISION, c.DATA_SCALE 
                FROM SYS.ALL_TABLES t 
                    INNER JOIN SYS.all_tab_columns c ON c.TABLE_NAME=t.TABLE_NAME AND c.OWNER=t.OWNER
                WHERE t.OWNER = 'MY_SCHEMA_NAME' AND t.Table_Name = 'MY_TABLE_NAME'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with an *estimate* number of rows (whose accuracy depends on the freshness of each table's statistics), you can just use column `NUM_ROWS` from `ALL_TABLES`:

```
SELECT 
    t.OWNER AS TABLE_SCHEMA, 
    t.Table_Name, 
    c.COLUMN_NAME, 
    c.DATA_TYPE, 
    t.NUM_ROWS, --> here
    ...
FROM all_tables t
INNER JOIN all_tab_columns c ...
```

Note that `DISTINCT` seem superfluous here - your query generates one record per column in the table.

*If* you really need the exact count, then you can use an inline query - but you need to hardcode the table name:

```
SELECT 
    t.OWNER AS TABLE_SCHEMA, 
    t.Table_Name, 
    c.COLUMN_NAME, 
    c.DATA_TYPE, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_schema_name.my_table_name) no_rows,
    ...
FROM all_tables t
INNER JOIN all_tab_columns c ...
WHERE t.OWNER = 'MY_SCHEMA_NAME' AND t.Table_Name = 'MY_TABLE_NAME'
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the exact number? The estimate value I'm getting seems really far off

Comment: @awdoibbbbbbb2: you will get more accurate results if you update the statistics of the table. I also updated my answer with a solution that gets your the exact count.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which SQL you are using but you might put the whole result into a temp table
like

```
INTO temp temp_table_count WITH NO LOG;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp_table_count;
```

Comment: Using oracle SQL

Comment: https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-private-temporary-table/ the reference

INSERT INTO ora$ppt_temp1(id,description)
VALUES(1,'Transaction-specific private temp table');

Answer (score 0):

https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-private-temporary-table/ the reference

```
INSERT INTO ora$ppt_temp_table_count(ADD ALL COLUMNS HERE 
COMMASEPARATED)
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM source_table
WHERE condition; <-- your query

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ora$ppt_temp_table_count;
```